# Subsetting and Indexing in For Loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, indexing, minimum

I am trying to collect the n number of smallest values in a dataset sorted by rank.

Here is my code:

```
testscript <- function(num) {
    df <- data.frame(State = paste0("State",sort(rep(1:2,10))),
                     City = rep(paste0("city",rep(1:10,2))),
                     Value = runif(n=20))
    vec <- NULL
    df$Rank <- ave(df$Value, df$State, FUN=rank)
    for (i in 1:num) {
         vec[i] <- df[df$Rank==[i],]
    }
}
```

The argument num is the number of smallest values that I want to collect.

When I run the function, I get the following error:

```
    Error: unexpected '[' in:
    "for (i in 1:num) {
          vec[i] <- df[df$Rank==["
```

Comment: Your function does not return a value.  Can you include code showing how you intend to use it?

Comment: testscript(3) should produce:

      State       City          Value         Rank
3    State1     city3    0.05694883    1
13  State2     city3   0.08323056     1
5    State1     city5     0.3006471     2
16  State2     city6     0.1483099     2
1    State1     city1      0.3988151    3
17  State2     city7      0.2782792    3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to get the n smallest values in a dataset sorted by rank, you can do this with the `order` and `head` functions -- no need for the for loop:

```
num <- 10
head(df[order(df$Rank),], num)
#     State   City        Value Rank
# 7  State1  city7 0.1075155728    1
# 19 State2  city9 0.0008769566    1
# 5  State1  city5 0.2829263743    2
# 17 State2  city7 0.0407836910    2
# 6  State1  city6 0.4697333111    3
# 14 State2  city4 0.1197360896    3
# 3  State1  city3 0.4853360290    4
# 11 State2  city1 0.1766399497    4
# 10 State1 city10 0.5803764823    5
# 13 State2  city3 0.3109590847    5
```

Comment: why not just `head(df[order(df$Rank), ])`? What is the `num` for?

Comment: @Maiasaura `num` indicates the number of rows to take.

Comment: I want to be able to specify the number of smallest values.

Comment: @LeeorShimron change `num` to indicate the number of smallest values you want. It is set to 10 in my example.

Comment: @josilber Thanks! That seems to work. Though, I am still curious why the for loop doesn't work.

Comment: @LeeorShimron it didn't work because of the brackets around the `i`. See Tim's answer. Also, even with that fixed, your function doesn't return a value.